# HTTPS only on subdomain

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, mod-ssl

I have a Jenkins install at `ci.example.com`, and a static site at `example.com`.  The Jenkins install is configured to use HTTPS exclusively.  I'm a cheapskate, so I only have a certificate for the `ci.example.com` domain.  My Apache config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ci.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://ci.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName https://ci.example.com
    ServerAlias ci
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ci.example.com.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ci.example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ci.example.com.ca-bundle

    # Some proxy magic to make Jenkins work
</VirtualHost>
```

(actually, this is an Ubuntu machine, so I just pulled the relevant site config files and concatenated them; there's lots of other mostly-irrelevant config stuff in other files)

When I navigate to `https://example.com`, I get a certificate error, because Apache is choosing the only available vhost on port 443.  Is it possible to give the user a less-scary-looking connection refused error?

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/568897/apache-serving-wrong-document-root) says I can't just redirect from HTTPS to HTTP without a cert, which makes sense since you need to establish an SSL connection (with a cert) before you can send a 3xx.  But I don't want to send a 3xx (or a 4xx, for that matter).  I just want to refuse the connection entirely.  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With your current setup:**

No, you can't just refuse the connection..
 
that is, without also refusing connections to the ci.example.com vHost.

Bite the bullet and get a cert for the additional hostnames, or get a wildcard cert, or use cloudlfare, etc or accept the browser warnings when people try to use HTTPS for a vhost for which you have no cert.

**Alternatively:**

Host ci.example.com. on a different IP address than example.com.
On the IP used for example.com, don't listen on 443.
This will result in the refused connection that you seek.

*(it may not, however, be consistent with your stated cheapskate status)*

Answer (score 1):

You're not cheap, you're **lazy**. Go get a [free](https://www.startssl.com/?app=1) certificate and hope that your clients support [`SNI`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

Comment: I just tried to sign up for StartSSL.  First, I got repeated SSL errors on their signup page, and then after providing my information, I got an HTTP 405 saying "if you are a human, this should never have happened."  Frankly, this does not inspire confidence.